# Outlook 365 reorder mail accounts

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have 3 email accounts in Outlook 365 Desktop. How can I manually reorder them? I've tried to drag, right clicking. It looks like they are in alphabetical order. In Outlook 2010 you simply had to hold the mouse down on the left arrow and drag the account to put it in over or under other accounts. Seems simple but I can't figure out how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same setup and number of email accounts. I think the best you can do is have the default account at the top. I do not think there is any other flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the switch of the new version of Outlook turned on?
As far as I know, folder reordering is currently not supported in New Outlook for Windows, and this work is in progress and will be available in the future.

[image]

I suggest you stay in the classic Outlook until they are resolved, or you can switch the toggle to go between apps as often as you want.

Comment: Yes I'm using the new Outlook. Thanks for answering my question